# How to connect Classic ASP code to FreeSQLDatabase.com database?

Tags: mysql, vbscript, asp-classic, adodb, freesqldatabase

I created a free SQL database from https://www.freesqldatabase.com/

Upon creating the database, I was given a server/database host link, port number, database name, username, and password.

Using that information, how do I connect to the database with Classic ASP?

This is the code I've written so far -

```
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 UNICODE Driver};Server=sql3.freesqldatabase.com;Database=dbname;User=username;Password=password;Option=3;"
```

It doesn't seem to do the work, though. What changes should I make so that I am able to connect to this database successfully? The database is hosted through PHPMyAdmin but I don't think that matters.

Comment: Presumably you've downloaded and installed the MySQL ODBC driver on your server, and your connection string reflects the version of the driver you have installed

Answer (score 1):

You mention that the provider provided;

> *"server/database host link, port number, database name, username, and password"*

However, I don't see a reference to a [port number](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-odbc-5-2/specifying-tcpip-port/) in the connection string.

Here is an example with a port number;

```
conn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 UNICODE Driver};Server=sql3.freesqldatabase.com;Database=dbname;Port=1234;User=username;Password=password;Option=3;"
```

If you intend to connect remotely via TCP/IP the correct port number will be required or the provider will likely block the incoming traffic at their firewall.